# Storing contract definition on the consumer side for messaging communication

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

Is it possible to store contract definition on the consumer side?

In the documentation and samples repository (spring-cloud-contract-samples) there are only examples and descriptions of the contract being stored in the common repo or on the producer side. As I understand this supports the architecture where one producer publishes messages and one or many consumers are consuming them. In this case, it actually makes sense to store the contract on the producer side.

But I have a system where many producers are publishing messages to a single queue and there's only one consumer to that queue. I think in this case it would be better to store the contract definition on the consumer side. For example, when adding a new producer, it could use the existing contract stored in the consumer, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that's not possible, and that's the case for a reason... That's because we need to produce a stub. That stub needs to be verified against the producer of the message (via autogenerated tests). Currently, we have no way of knowing that for a given producer, the contracts are defined by given consumers e.g. A, B and C. We need this knowledge cause we need to generate tests from these contracts.